# Copying page into div gets empty div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found some code that is supposed to load a div with a page content (designed to show an rss feed that I am trying to modify to just show a web page) and refresh it with a timer, but although I see it hit the page, it does not show the div content of the other page.  I am looking for how to fix this so it will work.

Here is the code in test.jsp, which is the main page called:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Auto Refresh Div Content Demo | jQuery4u</title>
    <!-- For ease i'm just using a JQuery version hosted by JQuery- you can download any version and link to it locally -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
    (function($)
    {
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $.ajaxSetup(
                    {
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#test').hide();
                            $('#loading').show();
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('#test').show();
                        },
                        success: function() {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('#test').show();
                        }
                    });
            var $container = $("#test");
            $container.load('http://localpage.com/rolestable.jsp?acronym=PEANUT #DOMTarget');
            var refreshId = setInterval(function()
            {
                $container.load('http://localpage.com/rolestable.jsp?acronym=PEANUT #DOMTarget');
            }, 9000);
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Test</h2>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="test"></div>
<img src="http://localpage.com/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loading" alt="loading" style="display:none;" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The page it calls (i.e., rolestable.jsp):

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<jsp:useBean id="abean" class="abean.com" scope="page">
<jsp:setProperty name="nuts" property="*" />
<jsp:setProperty name="nuts" property="acronym" value="${param['acronym']}" />
</jsp:useBean>


<head>
<!-- <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20"> -->
<style>
    #acronym {
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    table, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        word-wrap: break-word;
    }
    #acronym th {
        font-size: 1.1em;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 4px;
        background-color: deepskyblue;
        color: #ffffff;
    }
</style>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

<title>Nutty Test</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jscript.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var acronym = "";

    function init() {
        tableCreate();
    }

    function domTarget(t,s) {
       var target = document.getElementById(t);
        target.innerHTML = "";
        target.innerHTML = s;
    }

    function tableCreate(){
        acronym = "${param['acronym']}";

        var table = header + "<table id='acronym'>";
        var head = "<thead>";

        head += "<tr>";
        head += "<th>Administrators</th>";
        head += "<th>Developers</th>";
        head += "<th>Observers</th>";
        head += "<th>Users</th>";
        head += "</tr>";
        head += "</thead>";

        table += head;

        var body = "<tbody>";
        body += "<tr>";
        body += "<td>";

        // Administrators
        var cell = "";
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${abean.projAdministrators}" varStatus="status" >
            if (cell == "") {
                cell = "${item}";
            } else {
                cell +=", ${item}";
            }
        </c:forEach>
        body += cell;
        body += "</td>";

        // Developers
        body += "<td>";
        cell = "";
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${abean.projDevelopers}" varStatus="status" >
        if (cell == "") {
            cell = "${item}";
        } else {
            cell +=", ${item}";
        }
        </c:forEach>
        body += cell;
        body += "</td>";

        // Observers
        body += "<td>";
        cell = "";
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${abean.projObservers}" varStatus="status" >
        if (cell == "") {
            cell = "${item}";
        } else {
            cell +=", ${item}";
        }
        </c:forEach>
        body += cell;
        body += "</td>";

        // Users
        body += "<td>";
        cell = "";
        <c:forEach var="item" items="${abean.projUsers}" varStatus="status" >
        if (cell == "") {
            cell = "${item}";
        } else {
            cell +=", ${item}";
        }
        </c:forEach>
        body += cell;
        body += "</td>";

        body += "</tr>";
        body += "</tbody>";
        table += body;
        table += "</table>";

        domTarget("DOMTarget",table);
    }
    window.onload = init;

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="DOMTarget" name="DOMTarget" >

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser developer tool shows that it got to the page and it shows it received the acronym parameter (i.e., PEANUT) value, but the DOMTarget div is empty.  If I go to the page directly it works fine.

Note that I see with chrome if you open developer tools and click on network tab that it keeps adding every time the timer runs a rolestable.jsp page call with parameter, and if you click on any of those they pop up the page with the content that I want to see in the div.  I am guessing this means the load is working as far as calling the page, but it is just not going in the test div.

Comment: have you checked if  acronym inside tablecreate() fct is not null ?

Comment: Yes, if I look at the developer tool information it shows the variable is receiving the paramete value.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could maybe don't work because you can't access $container within setInterval()

JS:

```
$.ajaxSetup(
                    {
                        cache: false,
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            $('#test').hide();
                            $('#loading').show();
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('#test').show();
                        },
                        success: function() {
                            $('#loading').hide();
                            $('#test').show();
                        }
                    });
            var $container = $("#test");
            $container.load('http://localpage.com/rolestable.jsp?acronym=PEANUT #DOMTarget');
            var refreshId = setInterval(function()
            {
                $("#test").load('http://localpage.com/rolestable.jsp?acronym=PEANUT #DOMTarget');
            }, 9000);
```

Comment: Interesting, but why wouldn't $container still be in scope?  I changed the code a bit and changed it to not use .load and instead use:    <code> $container.html('<object data="http:////localpage.com//rolestable.jsp?acronym=PEANUT">'); </code> and voila stuff appears in the div.  It does not show wonderful iframe scrollbars and stuff, so it sucks, but at least it pops up.  I can try and work out the smallness issue next.  I need to see if refresh is less visible with this over using the meta refresh method too.

Comment: The solution just plan sucks.  It is much more notable than just a good old meta refresh.  I guess the way to go is have the ajax just populate/refresh the table data instead of just trying to replace the table with data.